# Is it legal,safe or purposeful to control if a subclass is conforming a protocol in base class

Tags: swift

I wonder if it's a good practice to control if a protocol is conforming in base class. In my opinion, it's not a good practice because the base class should include all the properties and methods that should be related to sub classes. And the base class should not know the protocol that the sub class is conforming or not.

An example usage;

```
class BaseClass: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       if let self = self as? SomethingAble {
          self.doIt()
       }
   }
 }

protocol SomethingAble {
   func doit()
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: `protocol SubClass: BaseClass, SomethingAble {` makes no sense. Did you mean `class`?

Comment: sorry, just editted.

Comment: You've answered your question already "the base class should not know the protocol that the sub class is conforming or not."

Comment: @Gereon what's your advice to achieve a behaviour like implementing something in all subclasses except several of them? This was the first solution that come to my mind but it's not a good solution.

Comment: @AlicanYilmaz Well, implement it in the subclasses. You can even add another subclass level.

Comment: @Sulthan But in this case the subclass is only used for only for our little behaviour? Is it good? :) Almost an empty class...

Comment: @AlicanYilmaz Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: The protocol here is a red herring. Your `if let self = self as? SomethingAble` Is just the same as `if let self = self as? SomeSubclass` — You would never say that because the code would all go in the SomeSubclass override. Otherwise what is subclassing for? You might as well throw away polymorphism altogether if you’re going to write code like that.

Comment: “what's your advice to achieve a behaviour like implementing something in all subclasses except several of them?” Another subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to implement optional protocols so one of them:

**First:**
Swift has a feature called `extension` that allow us to provide a default implementation for those methods that we want to be optional.

```
protocol SomethingAble {
    func optionalMethod()
    func notOptionalMethod()
}

extension SomethingAble {

    func optionalMethod() {
        //this is a empty implementation to allow this method to be optional
    }
}
```

**Second:**

```
@objc protocol SomethingAble {
    @objc optional func optionalMethod()
}
```

Comment: Imagine you have 1500 + 5 classes, I want to do the same behaviour in 1500 classes except the 5. But all the 1505 classes inherits from BaseClass.

Comment: @AlicanYilmaz: No, Using first way You need to add extension only once then all 1500 classes not required optional methods

Comment: 1500 classes makes a design smell - you really have that many? with different implementations of methods on each one? Yu could ut the base as not incluin the rotocol an the the 5 and another abstract inherit from that and the protocol is added to that abstract

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use custom `delegate` variable

```
 class myViewController: UIViewController {

      var customDelegate : UIViewController?
      .
      .
      .
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          if delegate is MainVC {
              //do what you want.
          } else {
              // git la burdan ;) 
          }
      }
   .
   .
   }
```